# How do I delete a Git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I am in a bit of a quandary. I accidentally merged code between two Git repositories. For whatever reasons, the repo names were same and one of the repo's URL had changed before I came to know of it. So I ended up merging code from two different projects. Here is the illustration from the repository commits.

[image: Merged repo]

I have not named any branches (have been working on HEAD all along). How do I delete one of the commits (specifically the orange one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
git reset --hard 628612ac
```

If you are sure you don't have anything in the current working copy that you will need. This will put the `HEAD` to the commit you had before the merge. Nothing is actually deleted - the other commits become unreachable and will be garbage collected sometime in the future.

Another option is to use [`git-revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html):

```
git revert -m 1 e90aeed8
```

This will keep your history. It creates a new commit that reverts everything that e90ae... did.

Here's a good read about the subject: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

And also here: http://git-scm.com/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html

Comment: Thanks!! git revert did the trick locally and git reset --hard worked on the remote repo. The links are very helpful indeed!